# Java -read from a text file and Add item( string , arrayList) to hashmap

Tags: java, arraylist, hashmap

This is the text file : output1.txt

```
zzz ***Wed Jan 15 10:00:03 +08 2020
a : 20
b : 30
c : 40
zzz ***Wed Jan 15 11:00:03 +08 2020
a : 22
b : 24
c : 25
```

I am trying to add the date in String and a,b,c as `ArrayList` into a hash map:

Desired output:

```
{zzz ***Wed Jan 15 10:00:03 +08 2020=[a : 20, b : 30, c : 40],
 zzz ***Wed Jan 15 11:00:03 +08 2020=[a : 22, b : 24, c : 25]}
```

My code:

```
    String dateString ="";
    ArrayList<String> value = new ArrayList<String>();
    HashMap<String, ArrayList> result = new HashMap<String, ArrayList>();

    String fileName = "/Users/--/Downloads/output1.txt";
    File file = new File(fileName);
    FileReader fr = new FileReader(file);
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(fr);
    String line;

    while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
        if (line.startsWith("zzz")) {
            dateString = line;
        } else {
            value.add(line);
        }
        result.put(dateString, value);
    }
    System.out.println(result);
```

And the result I got is:

```
{zzz ***Wed Jan 15 10:00:03 +08 2020=[a : 20, b : 30, c : 40, a : 22, b : 24, c : 25], 
 zzz ***Wed Jan 15 11:00:03 +08 2020=[a : 20, b : 30, c : 40, a : 22, b
```

Comment: What are the types of `value` and `result`? What is the code for `add()` and `put()`? Please post these classes too.

Comment: what is `value`? where is it defined? where is it initialized? and I am pretty sure that you would want to re-initialize when new `zzz` line is found

Comment: sorry about that, my initialisation is :                                                   
    String dateString ="";
    ArrayList<String> value = new ArrayList<String>();
    HashMap<String, ArrayList> result = new HashMap<String, ArrayList>();

Comment: @cam Please edit your question with this *new* code.

Comment: @ScaryWombat thanks for remind, i edited it. Also, i solved my issue. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Here is example code.

We use [`Scanner`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Scanner.html) to parse each line of the input string. The scanner object is defined within a [try-with-resources](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html), to be automatically closed.

We define a date-time formatting pattern with [`DateTimeFormatter`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html) to match your funky input. Tip: Teach the publisher of your data about the [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) standard defining practical formats for exchanging date-time values as text.

As our key, we parse the first of each four lines to get a [`OffsetDateTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/OffsetDateTime.html) object. This is the key in our [`Map`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Map.html). Our map is defined concretely as a [`TreeMap`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/TreeMap.html), to keep the keys in sorted chronological order.

We build a [`List`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/List.html) of [`Integer`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Integer.html) numbers parsed from the expected "a, b, c" values. We use the new [`List.of`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/List.html#of(E,E,E)) feature for simple syntax in building a `List` object of an unknown concrete type. A `List` keeps the elements in the order in which they were added, so we know the first is `a`, second is `b`, and third is `c`.

```
String s = "zzz ***Wed Jan 15 10:00:03 +08 2020\n" +
        "a : 20\n" +
        "b : 30\n" +
        "c : 40\n" +
        "zzz ***Wed Jan 15 11:00:03 +08 2020\n" +
        "a : 22\n" +
        "b : 24\n" +
        "c : 25";

DateTimeFormatter f = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern( "'zzz ***'EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss x uuuu" ).withLocale( Locale.US );
Map < OffsetDateTime, List < Integer > > momentCounts = new TreeMap <>();
try (
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner( s ) ;
)
{
    while ( scanner.hasNextLine() )
    {
        OffsetDateTime moment = OffsetDateTime.parse( scanner.nextLine() , f );
        List < Integer > counts = List.of(
                Integer.valueOf( scanner.nextLine().replace( "a : " , "" ) ) ,
                Integer.valueOf( scanner.nextLine().replace( "b : " , "" ) ) ,
                Integer.valueOf( scanner.nextLine().replace( "c : " , "" ) )
        );
        momentCounts.put( moment , counts );
    }
}

System.out.println( "momentCounts = " + momentCounts );
```

When run.

> momentCounts = {2020-01-15T10:00:03+08:00=[20, 30, 40], 2020-01-15T11:00:03+08:00=[22, 24, 25]}

Comment: hi, thanks for your help. If you free pls help me to see this issue as well. Thanks.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59766445/java-convert-offsetdatetime-timestamp-to-regulartimeperiod-to-plot-time-serie

Answer (score 0):

Just init the new array before you read the new line start with "zzz".

```
String fileName = "/Users/--/Downloads/output1.txt";
File file = new File(fileName);
FileReader fr = new FileReader(file);
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(fr);
String line;

while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
    if (line.startsWith("zzz")) {
        dateString = line;
        value = new ArrayList<>();
    } else {
        value.add(line);
    }
    result.put(dateString, value);
}
System.out.println(result);
```

Comment: It's works, thanks for help ! I am new to Java, thanks for your help.

Comment: I have the same issue. I tried to use your approach but I couldn't handle with the issue. Can you help me? Here is the link : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74489775/read-values-from-txt-file-with-different-kinds-of-values-orderly-based-on-id-in