# Java - Convert OffsetDateTime/ timestamp to RegularTimePeriod to plot time series graph (Jfreechart)

Tags: timestamp, jfreechart

I currently trying to plot a graph using *Jfreechart*, and it accept only `RegularTimePeriod`

My date String is:
`zzz ***Wed Jan 15 10:00:03 +08 2020`

From [this Question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59747177/642706) I learned to parse such a string into an `OffsetDateTime` object. By calling `OffsetDateTime` I get this string:

> 2020-01-15T10:00:03+08:00

Then I was trying to make it into `RegularTimePeriod`, specifically "second". I'm lost and confused about the conversion.

Here is my code:

```
TimeSeries s1 = new TimeSeries("Something");

DateTimeFormatter f = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern( "'zzz ***'EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss x uuuu" ).withLocale( Locale.US );
OffsetDateTime moment = OffsetDateTime.parse( "zzz ***Wed Jan 15 10:00:03 +08 2020" , f );
Timestamp timestamp =Timestamp.valueOf(LocalDateTime.ofInstant(moment.toInstant(), ZoneOffset.UTC));

s1.add(timestamp,value);
```

error:
Timestamp cannot be converted to RegularTimePeriod

Javadoc from [*JFree*](http://www.jfree.org/) project:

- [`RegularTimePeriod`](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/org/jfree/data/time/RegularTimePeriod.html)
- [`TimeSeries`](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/org/jfree/data/time/TimeSeries.html)

Comment: Provide a link to the Javadoc of the class you want to use.

Comment: Use your `Timestamp` to create a `org.jfree.data.time.Second`. If problems remain, please [edit] your question to include a [mcve] that shows your revised approach.

Comment: @BasilBourque Here: http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/index.html   (Class JFreeChart, TimeSeries)

Comment: Provide additional details as edits to your Question rather than as Comments.

Comment: @BasilBourque sure

Comment: This site is meant to be a knowledge base for posterity, more like Wikipedia than a casual chat site or messaging thread. So please use proper typing, appropriate uppercase/lowercase, and real words. I cleaned up some if it for you here.